# Is there a way to wrap every single entry of an numpy.ndarray into a separate array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm facing some problems getting an array into the right shape to use it as an input into a convolutional neural net:

My array has the shape `(100,64,64)`, but I'd need it to be `(100,64,64,1)`. I realize it looks a bit odd, but I basically want to pack every single entry into a separate array.

A simplified example, with a 2D array, where the analogous would be from `(3,3)` to `(3,3,1)`:

```
[[0,1,0],        [[[0],[1],[0]],
 [1,1,1],         [[1],[1],[1]],
 [0,0,1]]         [[0],[0],[1]]]
```

Is there a convenient way to do this using numpy?

I've tried to use the function `numpy.reshape`: With which I know, how to "add" another array wrapping the original one.

```
import numpy as np

data = data.reshape((1,)+data.shape)
```

This gives the output for `data.shape`: `(1,100,64,64)`.
Is there a way to add a dimension at the "inner end"?

If I try `data.reshape(data.shape+(,1))`, I get an invalid syntax error.

Comment: `(,1)` is not a valid Python expression, hence the syntax error.  `(1,)` makes a 1 element tuple, which is what you want to join to `shape` tuple.  The comma isn't a place holder; it's what makes a `tuple`.  This is an obscure corner of Python syntax, but essential when working with `numpy` `shape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape using:

```
a[:,:,None]
```

Or, programmatically (works for any number of dimensions):

```
a.reshape((*a.shape,1))
```

example

```
a = np.array([[0,1,0],
              [1,1,1],
              [0,0,1]])

# array([[0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1]])


a[:,:,None]  # or a.reshape((*a.shape,1))

# array([[[0], [1], [0]],
#        [[1], [1], [1]],
#        [[0], [0], [1]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=ellipsis#Ellipsis) plus `None` to the arrays indexer:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])

>>> a[..., None]
array([[[0],
        [1],
        [0]],

       [[1],
        [1],
        [1]],

       [[0],
        [0],
        [1]]])
```

(Credit to [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535245/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-every-single-entry-of-an-numpy-ndarray-into-a-separate-ar/70535313?noredirect=1#comment124685570_70535313))

Comment: `a[..., None]` is enough if you just want to add a new trailing dimension.  '...' represents an flexible number of ':'`.

Answer (score 2):

As the [docs points out](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), when the shapes are compatible as yours are, you can directly change the shape of the array too:

```
a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1]
])

a.shape += (1,)
a

# array([[[0], [1], [0]],
#        [[1], [1], [1]],
#        [[0], [0], [1]]])
```